# Is the Apollo Federation loosely coupling?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-federation

I am pretty new to microservices architecture and Apollo Federation. I am curious: is the Apollo federation really loosely coupled? Because if a subgraph doesn't work in Node.js, the gateway also doesn't work. So the whole system will crash because of a subgraph, even if other ones work properly.

Comment: "whole system will crash because of a subgraph" what do you mean? Apollo server doesn't let you deploy an invalid subgraph. Or do you mean when querying? If one field fails to resolve in a GraphQL query, it doesn't block the rest of the query fields. That's why GraphQL queries always return HTTP 200 status codes, because if one field fails, it shouldn't "fail" the entire query

Comment: For instance, a subgraph stopped for some reason after deployment to any server, and the gateway won't connect to the subgraph. So it will give an error. Will it then allow us to use other subgraphs in this situation?

Comment: With apollo federation, this ticket mentions that the gateway still comes up even if can't connect to a specific subgraph https://github.com/apollographql/federation/issues/349